# The code to count all the 5digit number pairs such that their addition does not involve any carrying, but the code is not giving any output?

Tags: python, list, output

```
l=0
temp=[]
for i in range(10000,100000):
    for j in range(11000,12000):
        n1=str(i)
        n2=str(j)
        for k in range(0,5):

            a=int(n1[k])
            b=int(n2[k])
            if a+b<=9:
                s=(a,b)
                temp.append(s)
        if len(temp)==5:
            l+=1
            temp.clear()
print(l)
```

this code is not giving any output, it is meant to count the number of 5digit number such that their sum does not involve any carrying

Comment: Are (10000, 10001) and (10001, 10000) considered to be one pair or two?

Answer (score 3):

Your code does print stuff out, but the execution time is very high. Your aim should be on reducing the runtime of your code.

One way of doing this is by realizing that for a five-digit number `a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5`, there are `(9 - a_1)` ways to pick the first digit of the other summand, `(10 - a_2)` ways to pick the second digit of the other summand, `(10 - a_2)` ways to pick the third digit of the other summand, etc. (In this calculation, we use `9` rather than `10` for the first digit. This is because we can't use `0` for the first digit, but we can for the others.)

By using this observation, we can use a single `for` loop, greatly enhancing the runtime. This should run nearly instantaneously.

```py
total = 0
for i in range(10000, 100000):
    summand_count = 1
    while i != 0:
        if i < 10:
            summand_count *= (9 - (i % 10))
        else:
            summand_count *= (10 - (i % 10))
        i //= 10
    total += summand_count

print(total)
```

Comment: You're lucky that you've got a positive result. Try counting two digit numbers ;)

Comment: Oh shoot, yeah. I'll fix it in a minute. How'd you land on `329422500`, by chance?

Comment: I've provided a formula

Comment: Where do the 36, the 55, and the 4 come from? I'm getting something in the area of 147 million using the above program.

Comment: There's another small issue in your code. The first digit should be processed differently than the others.

Comment: Alright, now I think I've got it.

Comment: Yep, it is correct now!

Comment: I'm not willing to give a full explanation of my answer because this question is obviously a homework task and I don't want to spoil a good task for the teacher. I can give an explanation to you in pm (twitter or whatever).

Comment: Sure, I've added my contact information in my bio.

Comment: I've written an email.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can solve this problem without any loops at all: 36*55^4 == 329422500

Test:

```
s = 0
for i in range(10, 100):
    I = str(i)
    for j in range(10, 100):
        J = str(j)
        for k in range(2):
            if int(I[k]) + int(J[k]) >= 10:
                break
        else:
            s += 1

print(s)
```

1980

If you want to count distinct pairs in the sense that (10000, 10001) and (10001, 10000) is the same pair, the result will be `(36*55^4-4*5^4)/2+4*5^4 == 164712500`

Test:

```
s = 0
for i in range(10, 100):
    I = str(i)
    for j in range(i, 100):
        J = str(j)
        for k in range(2):
            if int(I[k]) + int(J[k]) >= 10:
                break
        else:
            s += 1

print(s)
```

1000